# How to get images alt using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add data-title and data-lightbox and get Images alt inside.

the problem is, i have a similar outputs, from first image alt only!

How can we fix it?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var imagesalt = $('.box a img').attr('alt');
  $(".box a").attr("data-title", imagesalt);
  $(".box a").attr("data-lightbox", imagesalt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img1.jpg" alt="Text 1">
  </a>
  <div class="img-block"></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img1.jpg" alt="Text 2">
  </a>
  <div class="img-block"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <a data-lightbox="text 1" data-title="text 1" href="#">
    <img src="img1.jpg" alt="Text 1">
  </a>
  <div class="img-block"></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <a data-lightbox="text 1" data-lightbox="text 1" href="#">
    <img src="img1.jpg" alt="Text 2">
  </a>
  <div class="img-block"></div>
</div>
```

I tried writing the code more than one way, but not useful

Thanks

Comment: Please organize your code a little better. Where are the script tags that separate your html code from javascript??

Answer (score 2):

Your query is ambiguous, that's why!

When you request the "alt" attribute with `$(".box a img").attr("alt")`, you're taking in many objects, sure, but `attr()` is returning only the first result.

In pure jQuery, you'd do it with `.each()`:

```
$(".box a img").each(function(){
  var imageAlt = $(this).attr("alt");
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  parent.attr("data-lightbox", imageAlt);
  parent.attr("data-title", imageAlt);
});
```

That should give you the behaviour you expect.

Comment: thank you, it's working fine! , but what happen if image not have alt ?

Comment: @AliNajm if the image doesn't have an alt, the variable `imageAlt` will be `undefined`. You may want to include something like `if typeof imageAlt is undefined then imageAlt = ""` (CoffeeScript). Just some sort of check if it matters.

Comment: I need to add IF not have alt

Comment: @AliNajm if this worked for you, be sure to accept the answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over each of the divs with the class of 'box' - then find the image within it, get the alt text of that and apply it as the data attribute of the div. Note I put in a console.log to demonstrate the alt text is being found correctly. Ypu can use the console inspector to see that the data attribute is being applied to the divs correctly.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".box").each(function(){
    var imageAlt = $(this).find('img').attr('alt');
    $(this).attr("data-title", imageAlt);
    console.log(imageAlt);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
<a href="#">
<img src="img1.jpg" alt="Text 1">
</a>
<div class="img-block"></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
<a href="#">
<img src="img1.jpg" alt="Text 2">
</a>
<div class="img-block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this:

```
$('.box a img').each(function(){
  $(this).parent().find("a").attr("data-title", $(this).attr("alt");
  $(this).parent().find("a").attr("data-lightbox", $(this).attr("alt");
 })
```

Answer (score -1):

The .attr() method gets the attribute value for only the first element in the matched set.
But, the .attr() method sets the attribute value for every element in the matched set.

[enter link description here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: read our [Answer] page for hints on what constitutes a good answer. this is not one of them